# How to detect a circle using SteamVR SDK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shapes, virtual-reality, joystick

I am involved in a virtual-reality project using the HTC Vive device, Unity and the SteamVR SDK used to communicate with the Vive.

Thanks to the joysticks, the final user must draw some shapes (for example a circle) and the movements begin when he presses a joysticks' button.

From all the generated data (output from the joysticks), how could I detect a circle ?

Do you have some documentation on this ?

Comment: http://pub.ist.ac.at/~bauer/ulrich-bauer.org/pub/bauer-ParametricReconstruction.pdf

I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I understand your concern incorrectly here:

*You use joysticks to draw some shapes like circles in some apps like steamvr home,
and you want to detect what you have drawn using software. And maybe you want to show the result in real time in screen or save to a file.*

**That means you need the ability to get rendered images, and detect image content using algorithms like deep learning.**
HTC Vive device are compatible with openVR SDK:
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr

You can use openVR SDK to DIY a steamVR driver,and get images in real time using direct mode component in the SDK. **It has lot of works to do even before adding the detection algorithm**, because you need a steamvr driver that can used to execute steamVR.